# Google Places Android

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to get a list of places of a certain type like restaurants, nearby a certain latlng. I looked into the Google Places SDK for android but I couldn't find anything for this use case. It has the autocomplete and current place search but nothing for searching a certain type of places for a reference location. The Places web API has this feature but I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve the same with the Android SDK for Places. Something like below. It's an example from the Places API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/output?parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use google places Api

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Try to implement the below api with proper modification with your **Your_API_KEY**

Change Params: **radius** , **type**, **location**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=Your_API_KEY